# Actions showing up with doubled titles

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

We are having events show up with their titles duplicated twice. Ideally, we would like the site name to show up on the second line. We have a title, site_name, and description in our og: metadata.

Is there a way to configure these events to display these fields correctly?

[image: doubled titles]

Comment: i don't get it. are you developing a facebook "reader" app for scribd?

Comment: We are allowing users to automatically post scribd activity to their facebook feed.

Comment: ... that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: plz post a link to a sample object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the configuration section in the facebook developer interface to change this. It's under Apps > Edit Open Graph > Aggregations > (event type name), and then you can change the caption lines.